# jquery cannot change selected id css

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a problem selecting my element by id, first I was using brackets in my id like this `categories[1]` and etc. I just realised it's forbidden to use brackets in ids, I changed it to just like this `categories1`... But I still cannot select my element. With brackets I tried escaping it like this:

```
<script>
$( "#categories\\[<?php echo $categoryId ?>\\]" ).css( "margin-top", "-10px" );
</script>
```

It didn't work, when I changed ids to being without brackets I'm using this:

```
<script>
$( "#categories<?php echo $categoryId ?>" ).css( "margin-top", "-10px" );
</script>
```

But it still doesn't work. I had same issue before, but I simply used javascript instead of jquery and it worked fine. What could be the problem that this isn't working? There is also css file for this element, which is referring to it's `class` but I guess my code should overwrite it?
I just tried `<style>` directly and it works with this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #categories<?php echo $categoryId ?> {
        margin-top: -10px;
    }
    </style>
```

Why my jquery code won't work on it?

Edit:
It was funny mistake that I missed this script line in my file. That fixed my problem.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Avoid altering CSS like this. Make a separate CSS file with classes for each scenario and then use JS/jQ only to change the class(es) of the element.

Comment: Maybe problem in `<?php echo $categoryId ?>`?? Is it not null or smth else??

Comment: I suspect you are running that before the elements exist. Does it work wrapped in `$(function(){ $( "#categories<?php echo $categoryId ?>" ).css( "margin-top", "-10px" );})` ?

Comment: I'm 100% sure it's not null or anything, it's correct value, as I need, it works with `<style>` directly, so that's not the case, I'll try @charlietfl solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this :

```js
//$("[id='categories[<?php echo $categoryId ?>]']").css( "margin-top", "-10px" );
$("[id='categories[1]']").css({
  "color": "red",
  "margin-top": "10px"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="categories[1]">abcd</div>
```

Comment: `$("#categories\\[1\\]")` that OP tried works just fine here also

Comment: Yeah i know this is just alternative :)

Comment: My point is if one works no reason the other wouldn't. Root of the problem is not shown in question

Comment: It was stupid mistake by me, I just realised I didn't have `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in my file. That fixed my problem... Thanks everyone for answers!